# How do I test if EJB is running on JBoss AS 7 server

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

Again, many excellent answers from the fine folks here on SO.  I am still unable to connect.  But I believe Gimby might have had a good suggestion that there may be something wrong with the server or the beans.  According to the log file generated when JBoss started, my beans have been deployed.  The administrator of the server is unable to run the admin console for vulnerabilities reasons so there is no way to see if the beans are running.  Is there a command line tool that I could point him to for testing?  Is there a simple test I could write that would check the beans?  I have tried most everything I have found and others have suggested and keep getting various errors. most times being:
     javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: remote://:4647
I've encountered other errors as I have made changes to various files and code but this one is the most frequent.  If the call I make to the bean is right, and that is questionable, then how do I tell if the bean is even running or not>

Comment: Thanks for completely misquoting me and specifically naming me, that is really going to help someone to understand what you are talking about. And again you ask something entirely different from what you really want to know. You do not want to know if an EJB is running, you are asking about connectivity problems from a client to the server. And that is as much as I am going to say about this AGAIN.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some uncleared situations here.
Still I want to ask you, if your bean got a remote interface. 
You could use lookup to find your bean on this server.
You also could deploy for example a RESTservice on your jboss server, which look for your bean locally, so you dont have to specify any connection properties, but you would need the jndi name.

Hope this helps a bit, greets Jerome.